# RequireJS Problem sharing method and variable between 2 modules having dependencies

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, requirejs, amd

In require JS in asp.net MVC i am trying to access the variable and method used in another module. How to do it ? Provided my example as below

1. ParentPageA

Below JS For ParentPageA

require([
    'jquery',
    'bootstrap',
    'jqGrid'],
    function ($){

```
 $(function () {

 var messageToAlert = 'Sample Message'; //Message Could be dynamic
    function DOWork(){
        alert('hi'); //Or other code using Jquery table
        alert(messageToAlert);
        messageToAlert = 'Change message ';
    }

 });


}
```

2. PartialViewA In ParentPageA

   ```
   require([
   'jquery',
   'bootstrap',
   'jqGrid',
   'ParentPageA'],
   function ($,ParentPageA){


   //ParentPageA - is Undefined

    $(function () {

     //How to Access messageToAlert variable ?
     //How to Access DOWork()
     //Need to access back the changed MessageToAlert variable as well
    });


   }
   ```

Is define the only option ? if i use Define - will it still be able to load other dependent modules inside the define ? Since my functions & variables depend on other libraries to be able to run (like funcions which Jquery, Calendar etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed as below

```js
define('MYFUNCMOD', ['https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'] ,function(jQuery) {
  // Window settings 
  var Message = "Initial Message";
  function change() {
    this.Message = "Changed Triggered";
  }
  
  function docReadyDisp()
  {
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
   alert('docReadyDisp Doc Ready');
  
  });
  }

  return {
    Message: Message,
    change:change,
    docReadyDisp : docReadyDisp
  };
  
});


// (is run on dom load)
require(['https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js','MYFUNCMOD'], function(jQuery,system) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert(system.Message);
    system.change();
     alert(system.Message);
     system.docReadyDisp();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```